# Random Number Generation using srand() defining a variable

Tags: c, random, numbers

Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
Enemy.strength = srand((unsigned)time(NULL)) % 10;
```

Enemy.strength is an int

I did some research and i found you can't directly define a variable with rand/srand
such as:

```
a = rand();
```

I am just wondering why and if there is a way around this or what alternative you suggest

Language: C... not C++

Comment: did you search for `srand`? There are plenty of examples on SO on how to use this and on how it is different from `rand`. Please show some effort before posting here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`srand(seed)` returns void. It is for seeding the random number generator. `rand()` returns a pseudo-random integer between 0 and RAND_MAX (defined in stdlib.h).

So to get a random strength for your enemy you should do something like:

```
Enemy.strength = rand() % 10; // gives a strength between 0 and 9
```

You can place a call to `srand` somewhere in your code, but it only needs to be called once. It should be called before any calls to rand().

Answer (score 1):

srand() accepts the seed as its first argument. Simply place the call to srand() before you assign Enemy.strength and assign the return value of rand() to it instead.

## Example

```
srand((unsigned)time(NULL)), Enemy.strength = rand() % 10;
```

Comment: with a comma operator? what for?

Comment: No particular reason other than writing a quick and hasty example of the placement of srand() before rand() but I am certainly not trying to win any competitions by it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below links for further understanding
[srand](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/)
[rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/)